# VM shutting down on Android media player

Tags: android, media-player

I'm making an Android media player. In first step I have play all song from sdcard one by one and next prev pause functionality. I have done this.
but when I test my application like continuously pressing next prev.. next prev.. button my application crashed due to VM shutting down and get exception indexoutofbound.

Comment: I suggest that you post your logcat. But this does not look like a problem with android. How are you reading the media files? Are you reading them in to an array ? It looks like an array transversal problem. I will use an iterable collection.

Comment: to retrieve all mp3 i have use  Mp3Filter class that implements FilenameFilter  and return all mp3 song name and after than make file connection like this... File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
  if (home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter()).length > 0) {
   for (File file : home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter())) {
    songs.add(file.getName());

   }

   playSong(MEDIA_PATH + songs.get(currentPosition));
   


  }

Comment: can you put code of playsong m]ethod

Comment: This question is too brief and thus is arguably Unclear. I will try to close it.

Answer (score 0):

It is because after some forward button clicks your SD card has last song and than when you increase counter it will have no song in that index. So check condition before playing it that it should not be greater than some max value or less than from 0.

Comment: No chirag it's not prob i have already check this condition and when this condition occurred i have call  player function again with first song so it is rounded queue.